# List of MARKS. Duplicate lines

Tags: vim, editors

The numbered marks, are used for trace history of the cursor position in the last closed session vim...and ok.
therefore:

`0` contain last position of the cursor before close VIM,
`1` contain the penultimate position of the cursor before close VIM,
`2` third last...ecc.

But why i when view list (with command **:marks**) outs duplicate lines?

```
mark riga  col.file/testo
 '      1    1 #!/usr/bin/python2.7
 a     47   12 surname=scelta
 0      3    0 #
 1      3    0 #
 2      2    0 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 3      2    0 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 4      2    0 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 5      3    0 #
 6      3    0 #
 7      3    0 #
 8      2    0 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 9      2    0 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 "      3    0 #
 [      1    0 #!/usr/bin/python2.7
 ]      1    0 #!/usr/bin/python2.7
 ^      1    1 #!/usr/bin/python2.7
 .      1    0 #!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`:help viminfo-file-marks`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#viminfo-file-marks) says that duplicates should not happen:

> If the current cursor position is already present in '0 to '9, it is moved to '0, to avoid having the same position twice.

Apparently, this functionality was broken in Vim 7.4.1925; I've just [submitted a bug report against Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5733).